# Ref readonly property with class type

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.3

I'm trying to create a readonly property (c# 7.2 feature).

```
public class JobStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public ref readonly JobStatus Status => ref _jobStatus;
    private readonly JobStatus _jobStatus = new JobStatus
    {
        Id = 4
    };
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var job = new Job();
        job.Status.Id = 5;
    }
}
```

This code compiles successfully. I would expect some kind of error that I'm trying to update field of readonly property. Am I using *ref readonly* return feature incorrectly?

Comment: To me it seems you are updating a property of a reference type. If you would update Status itself, I would expect a compile time error, but this is just changing a property on an object, the readonly in my eyes doesn't come at play there

Comment: Only the JobStatus reference is readonly, i.e. you can't exchange the JobStatus object with another JobStatus object. However, you can freely change the contents of JobStatus. It's the same as if you had a classic getter-only property, i.e. `public JobStatus Status => _jobStatus` which by the way would be the common approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I found in [this article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/Readonly-References) you should understand it as the following

> Marking a parameter as “readonly ref” or “in” does not make the value it refers to immutable. While the function declaring the parameter cannot make changes to it, the value can be changed elsewhere. This doesn’t require multiple-threads, just a way to access the original variable the parameter refers to.

So, as your class isn't immutable, it can be changed elsewhere. This feature seems mostly about performance in passing the reference value around

Comment: Is it possible in C# to return a reference to const object like in C++? Without adding an extra layer of abstraction (like read-only interface).

Comment: @Yozer No, not as far as I can see. But having it returned as a getter only interface seems to be your best bet (although, consumers can of course always cast it back if they choose to do so)